# macro excel to copy value till blank cell and paste to next sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

i have a sheet with many rows and the number of rows may vary for different similar files.i need to get a script where i can copy the values in the rows  till the next row is blank and paste it to the next sheet.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Click on any cell in the first row you want to consider and run this small macro:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim rng As Range, sh As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim sName As String, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim r1 As Long, r2 As Long
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set rng = ActiveCell
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    sName = sh.Name
    r1 = rng.Row

    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        If Sheets(i).Name = sName Then
            j = i + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    For i = r1 To Rows.Count
        If wf.CountA(Cells(i, 1).EntireRow) = 0 Then
            Range(Cells(r1, 1), Cells(i - 1, 1)).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(j).Range("A1")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```